# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'el' of undefined on fullcalendar.js:4368

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony

I have a calendar application where when I add a new item on the calendar on this line of code:

```
$this.$blockCalendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent', {
    title: resources+"S x "+capacity+"C = "+(capacity*resources),
    start: start,
    end: end,
    allDay: false
    }, true);  
$this.$modal.modal('hide');
```

This is the code on the fullcalendar.js file:

[image]

On the console this is the error I'm getting:

[image]

Please help!

Comment: In order to help you, we need some use case to dig into the code, for this cases a custom event and screenshot is not enough.

BTW/ seems something about the HTML string structure you should fit in order to be able to create those segments  `seg`

Answer (score 2):

i fixed this with sticking jquery to version 3.4.1

```
npm i jquery@3.4.1
```

this occured after resetting my package-lock,
jquery 3.5.1 was now installed and fullcalendar 3.8.2 raised this error

Answer (score 0):

Simply make check if "el" is not false as well as "seg" is not undefined:

```
if(el && seg != typeof 'undefined')
```